# Passing a member function as standard function callback

Tags: c++

I've been struggling for hours with the same part of the code, and I cannot find any answer that can guide me.

I'm using a library, and a method requires to pass a callback as parameter. See [here](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/src/PubSubClient.h#L121).

```
PubSubClient& setCallback(MQTT_CALLBACK_SIGNATURE);
```

And I'm trying to trigger this method, from a member function, like this:

```
void HouseKeeper::callback(char* topic, uint8_t* payload, unsigned int length) {
    // Do something
}

boolean HouseKeeper::connect() {
    library.setCallback(callback);
}
```

The error compiler gives, is the following:

```
no matching function for call to
'PubSubClient::setCallback(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'

note: no known conversion for argument 1 from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'std::function<void(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>'
```

I'm quite new with C++, so even the basics are still far away from me.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Try using a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (calling the function) or [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead? Or if the callback function doesn't need to access `this` (i.e. it doesn't need to use member variables or call member functions) then perhaps make it `static`?

Comment: @ArnavBorborah sorry, autocompleted. Just removed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member functions take `*this` pointer as a first parameter, so your function signature is actually:

```
void(HouseKeeper*, char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)
```

While std::function in library setCallback function takes:

```
std::function<void(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)>.
```

You have to change your `uint8_t*` to `unsigned char*` in your callback second parameter (thanks **Daniel H**), and also get rid of implicit `*this`.

- **You can use std::bind** to bind `*this` pointer to match setCallback() signature:

  ```
  std::function<void(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)> yourFunction = std::bind(&HouseKeeper::callback, this, _1, _2, _3);

  library.setCallback(yourFunction);
  ```
- **Or wrap your call in lambda function:**

  ```
  std::function<void(char*, uint8_t*, unsigned int)> yourFunction = [=](char* topic, uint8_t* payload, unsigned int length) {
      this->callback(topic, payload, length);
  }

  library.setCallback(yourFunction);
  ```

Comment: An `unsigned char` and a `uint8_t` are different types; I don’t think the `bind` version would work.

Comment: Also, there *is* a difference between `void(HouseKeeper*, char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)` (a regular function which accepts four parameters, the first of which is a `HouseKeeper*`) and `void (HouseKeeper::)(char*, unsigned char*, unsigned int)` (a member function of a `HouseKeeper`, accepting three parameters). A lot of standard library things treat them the same way, but a lot *don’t*, and the core language definitely doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" way to use callbacks is to declare your callback function static.